# Mouseleave jQuery event will remove the click effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

ok, I have a tabbed page and on click of a tab, I am showing a particular section and highlighting this tab to red background. Now I want to use the hover effect and on hover the tab should highlight to red background. It works but then when I mouseleave from the clicked tab, the background effect goes away.

In short, How do I highlight the tab to red background on hover for [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsukasa1989/5nB4P/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use some pure css for this:

```
#nav ul li:hover { background-color: red; }
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nB4P/23/)

**EDIT**

If you're trying to do this with jQuery (as a learning experience), I would define a new css class called hoverRed

```
.hoverRed { background-color: red; }
```

then use the hover function:

```
$("#nav ul li").hover(function() {
   $(this).addClass("hoverRed");
}, function() {
   $(this).removeClass("hoverRed");
});
```

The first function gets called when the hover begins, the second gets called when the hover ends (and the mouse leaves)

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nB4P/27/)

Comment: Great, i knew that, actually I am learning jquery events and was trying to use mouseenter, mouseleave, click on bind. what would be the jquery way??

Comment: using jQuery will be add more complexity, why do in jQuery somethinmg which can be easly done in CSS?

Comment: @EmmanuelN - I suspect OP is just doing this as a learning experience, but yeah, for a production project CSS would be much cleaner.

Comment: what is this concept called Adam, if you dont mind asking, having two functions for one event.

Comment: @Mike - it's not really a special concept, it's just a function jQuery gives you that accepts two functions.  One for when the hover starts, one for when it leaves. Check out the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for more info.

Comment: Hey Adam, sorry for troubling you again. If you see the fiddles that you posted http://jsfiddle.net/5nB4P/28/  and Virendra posted http://jsfiddle.net/5nB4P/28/    both work, though code looks similar. but how do you put everything in document.ready and he doesn't.

Comment: I think jsFiddle is doing something behind the scenes to let that work.  In your code you'd need it in document.ready (or in a script at the end of your body)

Comment: @Adam thanks Adam for your valuable advice. I was trying to use multiple css properties for li on hover like ul li:hover{background:#989898;color:red} but color red doesn't apply as the color is actually for the a tag link inside li. is there any work around for this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully.  You might consider taking the code you have and asking a new question to try to get this working correctly. -- oh wait - you want to apply red to the anchor inside the `li` -- something like this should work `$(this).find("a").css("..", "..");`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
#nav ul li:hover
{
  background: red;  
}
```

**Update**:
Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5nB4P/28/) for your mouseenter and mouseleave events. Here is the code that I added.

CSS

```
.lihover{background: red;}
```

jQuery

```
$("li").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).addClass("lihover");
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("lihover");
});
```

Comment: Why do you want it in jQuery, when you can easily do it with CSS?

Comment: Ok. If you are trying to learn than its fine, but this would be the a better solution to use in actual site.

Comment: Thanks Virendra, I have seen something for the first time, like .mouseleave(function() {$(this).removeClass("lihover")})

How is this dot[.] different from comma[,] as Adam has said

Comment: I am using dot [.] to add multiple functions and hence events to the same selector. In Adam's solution he is specifying 2 events in the same function. For hover() you can use the method which Adam suggested as it parses it as 1st function to be executed when hovered and 2nd when leaving the hover. I am using 2 different functions (as you wanted to use mouseleave) to implement the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks for this info, can I use bind(mouseenter) and bind(mouseleave) in your case

Comment: Yes, `.mouseleave( handler() )` is shortcut for `.bind('mouseleave', handler)`.